# remove is not a function in observable array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I made an observableArray in knockoutjs and I want to remove items from that array and tried as

```
self.work_days = ko.observableArray();

self.work_days().push(new WorkDayVM({}, date))
//WorkDayVM is a view model and date is date object this works fine and values are //assigned well in array.
```

But when trying to remove as

```
self.work_days.remove(days_to_remove[i]);
//also tried as self.work_days().remove(days_to_remove[i]);
```

I also tried as

```
for(var i = 0; i < days_to_remove.length; i++){
 self.work_days.remove(function(item){
   return item.work_days.day_string == days_to_remove[i].day_string;
 });
}
```

But I always get the same error

```
self.work_days().remove is not a function
```

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that reproduces your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

```
self.work_days().remove is not a function
```

Try calling .remove() (and .push()) directly on observableArray instead of trying to call it on the array value.
`self.work_days.remove instead` of `self.work_days().remove`

http://jsfiddle.net/NNU77/

Answer (score 1):

self.work_days().push(new WorkDayVM({}, date)) shoud be self.work_days.push(new WorkDayVM({}, date)) and then you should do the remove without the ()